# Realm swift sigabrt abort crash

Tags: swift, crash, realm, crashlytics, sigabrt

Crashlytics has reported a lot of crashes for our app, but I cannot conclude anything from stack trace, and I wasn't able to reproduce the crash.
It looks like this:
[image]

Inside MyScheduleTalksDownloader.parseDataAndSave method is only creating/updating realm object in commit transaction like this:

```
realm.create(T.self, value: ["id": id, "isFavorite": false], update: true)
```

Why would this code fail? Why isn't there a more descriptive error?

Our Realm version is 0.95.2 and I've seen some crash fixes is newer versions, however I need to confirm that those updates will solve our crashes.

EDIT: I've now discovered that it only occurs on 4s, 5 and 5c models, on both iOS8 and iOS9 if that helps.

Comment: You might have better luck opening a ticket on their GitHub page: https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues

Answer (score 0):

The stack trace indicates that you're hitting an assertion failure inside Realm's core database engine. Please [file an issue on GitHub](https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/new) or email help@realm.io with all information you have about this issue.